# Reading multiple JSON files with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have one main JSON file with multiple Writers and one of the properties for each number is an ID number.

So in the html I have reproduced these information as this using "append()":

```
Writer 1
properties of Writer1

Writer 2
properties of Writer2

Writer 3
properties of Writer3

...
```

Then I have multiple JSON files with those ID numbers as names (so I have as many JSONs as writers). Those files contains a list of published books for the corresponding writer.

So I want to create an HTML page for each writer with the list of published book.

like this:

```
Writer 1 (link to writer1 books)
properties of Writer1

Writer 2 (link to writer2 books)
properties of Writer2

Writer 3 (link to writer3 books)
properties of Writer3


----------New page for writer1-----------
book1
book2
book3
book4
book5

----------New page for writer2-----------
book1
book2
book3
book4
book5

----------New page for writer3-----------
book1
book2
book3
book4
book5
```

Is there any function which enables to do that? Not append() because I want new html pages

Comment: Look into using a *single page application* framework. Question is a bit vague

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate new html files? Client/Browser based JS isn't capable of this, if you're using node, maybe, I'm not sure. If you want to create a template to fill with Writer X's details, or clear the existing page and display only the details for Writer X, this is possible, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `$.getJSON(this.id+".js",function() { $("#page").html(.....) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running your javascript in the browser, there is no way to generate new html files. This would require your browser modifying your computer/server's file system, which it (with certain exceptions) does not have permission to do.

If you want to be able to dynamically generate pages as they're requested (for example, someone visits `yoursite.com/writer/1` and you want to display a page about the first writer), you have a long journey ahead of you. Many solutions to this exist, you should look into *[single page application frameworks](https://www.codeschool.com/beginners-guide-to-web-development/single-page-applications)*, which are based around the idea of dynamically generating pages given a url path and some database (in your case, just a json file). There are other frameworks out there too, SPA's are just very hot these days and can keep everything in JS.

One way to achieve 'page like' behaviour without implementing a framework or similar (which sounds like overkill in your case), would be to present popups or to restructure the page when links are clicked. For example, if someone clicked on 'writer 1' you could hide all other writers using [jQuery's .hide() method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), and append your extra info to the remaining writer. This wouldn't make new pages, but you could make it look like it would by [manipulating the browser's history.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: Your answer really helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Laura Before I learned about SPA's I basically build my own one for a Wordpress theme I made. Olivier.uk is entirely based on loading all the data in the page load, and hiding/restructuring it. Note that this link will not remain current, as the site is about to be renovated.